# Django returning webpage instead of JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to Django and am trying to implement a basic REST API in Django. I am having a news list in MySQL Database, and following various tutorials, successfully managed to implement a webservice that responds the news list.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/news_infos/

The above URL(local) produces the following page:

[image]

As you can see, I am getting a webpage here. But what I actually needed is that the above API to return just the json. I don't want to have this kind of pages available in my webservice, just the JSON response. Of course I can get it json only by appending `format=json` to the request. But that is not what I require. I want the web page to be gone and calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/news_infos/` to return the json instead.

Following is my views.py code:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import NewsContent, NewsInfo
from .serializers import NewsContentSerializer, NewsInfoSerializer

class NewsContentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = NewsContent.objects.all()[:10]
    serializer_class = NewsContentSerializer

class NewsInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = NewsInfo.objects.all()[:10]
    serializer_class = NewsInfoSerializer
```

Please let me know if any other code/info is required. Couldn't find any proper solution online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change **`DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES`** in `settings.py` as

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

It could be done ***view level*** by providing **`renderer_classes`** as,

```
from rest_framework import renderers


class MyView(...):
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
```

Comment: **simple is better than complex ;)**