# Django rest dont return json from java

Tags: java, json, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a json from Java, with a rest api developed in Django. The problem is that it apparently returns in html format. Testing the api from postman returns the json correctly, so I don't know if it's the error in Java or in Django. I test java pointing to eg jsonplaceholder, and it returns the json correctly, which is why I am inclined that the problem is in Django.

This is my django view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import *
# Create your views here.

class EmpleadoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmpleadoSerializer
    queryset = Empleado.objects.all()
```

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class EmpleadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Empleado
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from api_rest.views import *

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'empleados',EmpleadoViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns += [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Java code:

```
public boolean chequearDatos(String usuario,String contrasenia){

        boolean chequeo = false;
        try {
            InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String linea = bf.readLine();
            while (linea!=null){
                System.out.println(linea);
                linea = bf.readLine();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return chequeo;

    }
```

Calling http://localhost:8000/empleados/ print an html file, instead pointing to eg https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos print a json.

Thanks, sorry for my lenguage

**EDIT 1**

In my connection (java) i have got this:

```
public class ConexionAPI {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conexion;
    StringBuilder resultado;

    public ConexionAPI(String cadenaConexion){

        try {
            url = new URL(cadenaConexion);

            conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conexion.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            
            //conexion.setRequestProperty("Accept: application/json");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public boolean conectarAPI(){
        boolean conexionOK = false;
        try {

            conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
            if(conexion.getResponseCode()==200){
                conexionOK = true;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return conexionOK;

    }
```

and this is part of html that print:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    

      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
      

      <title>Empleado List – Django REST framework</title>

      
        
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css"/>
        

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/rest_framework/css/prettify.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/rest_framework/css/default.css"/>
        
      

    
  </head>
```

Comment: Solved! thanks everybody. Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800895/django-returning-webpage-instead-of-json

Answer (score 0):

Your url is registered as `empleados` instead o `employees` and are you tried calling `http://localhost:8000/empleados` with/without a slash at the end?

Comment: Sorry, translation error. I tried calling "http://localhost:8000/empleados/". This calling produces the same result that  "http://localhost:8000/empleados"